# Is there an event for detecting when grid is ready after rowData update?

Tags: ag-grid

I have a grid where rowData changes if the user refreshes the data. I need to scroll back to the same place (topScroll) where the user last scrolled before refreshing. In order to scroll to that point I need to detect the event where grid is ready every time after rowData changes. I see that onGridReady fires only once. Is there another event that I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use onRowDataChanged() event.

From the [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/) -

> **rowDataChanged**    The client has set new data into the grid using api.setRowData() or changing the rowData bound property.

Configure your `gridOptions` -

```
(rowDataChanged)="onRowDataChanged($event)"
```

Now you can implement your scrolling logic in `onRowDataChanged`

Comment: Note that `rowDataChanged` has been deprecated in favor of `rowDataUpdated`. Since v28.0.0 the `rowDataChanged` event is no longer fired [according to the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/changelog/?fixVersion=28.0.0).

Comment: rowDataUpdated exactly what I needed

Comment: There is also this event [gridReady](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-miscellaneous-gridReady) or [firstDataRendered](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-miscellaneous-firstDataRendered) that may help you.